# make enter key act like a tab key for jtextfield,jcombobox,jspinner in java

Tags: java, swing, focus, key-bindings

I want enter key to behave like tab key in my swing application.And this class is working fine for JTextFields.How can i do the same for JComboBox and Jspinner or for the other controls on the frame?kindly help.

```
class MyTextField extends JTextField {
    MyTextField(int len) {
    super(len);
    addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
      public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {
        int key = evt.getKeyCode();
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
          transferFocus();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Enter key has different mean for different components, removing this functionality could make you program less usable for the user.  You will, however, want to take a look at [How to Use the Focus Subsystem](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html). Look for examples using `setFocusTraversalKeys`

Comment: then you can't select and item from popup for JComboBox, editor in JSpinner can lost InputMask ???

Comment: And `ActionListener`'s won't be triggered...

Comment: Hey thanks.I have this requirement from client side.Client wants to use Enter key instead of Tab key.Is there any procedure where i can move focus from one control(jtextfield,jcombobox,jspinner) to another control(jtextfield,jcombobox,jspinner) using Enter key?

Comment: The problem is, you changing the expected behaviour of these components, not to mention the expectations of the user..."most" users know that tab is the transfer focus key...but what do we know ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Enter</kbd> has special meaning for most components in Swing, for example `JTextField` will trigger `actionPerformed` on registered `ActionListeners` when <kbd>Enter</kbd>  is pressed.  Modifying this behaviour may have unexpected results for your application and may confuse many users...

Having said that, the best way to change the focus traversal keys is to provide a `Set` of `KeyStroke`s to the `KeyboardFocusManager`.  This will (mostly) make the key's global.

Some component's supply there own focus traversal keys however, like `JTextArea` and `JTable`

Take a look at [How to use Focus Subsystem](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html) for more details

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestFocusTraversal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestFocusTraversal();
    }

    public TestFocusTraversal() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
                JTextField tf = new JTextField(5);
                tf.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        System.out.println("...");
                    }
                });
                add(tf);
            }

            add(new JScrollPane(new JTextArea(10, 10)));

            KeyStroke enter = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0);
            KeyStroke tab = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_TAB, 0);
            KeyStroke ctrlTab = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_TAB, KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK);
            Set<KeyStroke> keys = new HashSet<>();
            keys.add(enter);
            keys.add(tab);
            keys.add(ctrlTab);
            KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().setDefaultFocusTraversalKeys(KeyboardFocusManager.FORWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS, keys);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Note: None of the fields `ActionListener`s are triggered!

Comment: +1, @silent_killer, `thanks a lot...this is really what i wanted to implement.` - then you should "accept" the answer. This is the standard way to close the question when the answer is found.

Comment: It was my first post so kindly correct me for any mistakes.Thanks for the answers.