# How to add KeyListener to a Jdialog in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

I have the code below, my goal is to add a KeyListener to the input dialog in such a way that if the user presses the CTRL+N, the cursor should move to the next word in the textfield. But when I run the code, the KeyPressed method was not invoked. Can anyone help me explain why this method is never invoked?
Here is my code:

```
  public String prompt(String question, String title, String value) {
  //  System.out.println("Form has been invoked");
    ExtendedJDialog dialog = buildDialog(DialogType.PROMPT, title, question, value, null, ButtonType.OK, ButtonType.CANCEL);
    dialog.setResizable(false);
    UISupport.showDialog(dialog);
    dialog.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            String[] textFieldValue = value.split("\\s+");                
                if (e.isControlDown() && e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
                    System.out.println("Some keys were press");
                    // here I want to move the cursor to the next word of the textFieldValue.
                    // can't figure out how to make it work.
                
            }
        }
    });
    return dialog.getStringValue();
}
```

Comment: add the listener before showing

Comment: According to the code in your question, method `keyPressed` will only print something when the user presses both _Ctrl_ and right arrow key together. I suggest you move the following line: `System.out.println("Some keys were press");` to be the first line in method `keyPressed`. By the way, it is usually better to use [key bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) rather than `KeyListener`.

Comment: `KeyListener` won't work, because the component which it is registered to needs to be focusable AND have current focus, but your text fields will steal it (focus)

Comment: An overall better solution might be to make use of the focus traversal system [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18889744/make-enter-key-act-like-a-tab-key-for-jtextfield-jcombobox-jspinner-in-java/18890239#18890239)

Comment: (( the code is like `if (i == 0) { if (i == 2) { neverExecuted(); /* i cannot be 0 and 2 */ } }` )) Apart from that, maybe you should use the `InputMap` and `ActionMap`  of Swing components to do the key binding... see the 'The Java™ Tutorials' from Oracle: [How to Use Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Comment: @user16320675  I have just edited the code I posted initially, please you may take a look again

Comment: @MadProgrammer , actually, the textfield is what I'm aiming, i.e let say for example the textfied has text "  The New Castle  "   So if the user presses CTRL+N the cursor should move to the next word in the textfield. Assuming the Cursor was on  " The "  and the user presses CTRL+N, then the Cursor should move to " New , etc".

Comment: @kleopatra, Yes,  I have tried that too, it didn't work.

Comment: if it's a modal dialog, doing it after showing can't work, because that's a blocking call. Anyway, the real problem is the keylistener as such - see the other comments, which also point to possible solutions. Best to provide a [mcve] demonstrating what _exactly_ you are doing and expecting (vs. describing it in the comments with natural language)

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is that,  I'm trying to bind a KeyListener to a JDialog textfield to the do the following.

 1. The text field contains some text,

Current situation: If the user presses CTRL+>, the cursor will jump to the end of the sentence ( text in the JDialog textfield )

2. What I want is that:   If the user presses the CTRL+>, the cursor should move to the next word in the sentence ( in the case, the textfield in the JDialog )  and not to the end.
@MadProgrammer

Comment: So, like if you were to press [ctrl]+[left/right arrow] right now?

Comment: Right now if  I press [ctrl]+[left/right arrow] , it jumps from end to end, but I want it moves from word to word. @MadProgrammer

Comment: [ctrl]+[left/right arrow] moves between words for me - maybe on windows it's [alt]

Answer (score 2):

> actually, the textfield is what I'm aiming, i.e let say for example the textfied has text " The New Castle " So if the user presses CTRL+N the cursor should move to the next word in the textfield. Assuming the Cursor was on " The " and the user presses CTRL+N, then the Cursor should move to " New , etc".

So, assuming you want to move to the start of the next word, then you could simply do...

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField("This is a test");
InputMap im = textField.getInputMap();
im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_N, KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK), "caret-next-word");
```

`caret-next-word` is already mapped to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Key pad right</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>

Comment: Thank so much @MadProgrammer,  but please can you give me some hint on how to bind / map **caret-next-word**  to the keys, please, I don't really understand what you mean  "  ** caret-next-word already mapped to**

Comment: The code I've post is how you do it. `caret-next-word` a pre-existing key binding to a pre-existing action, which is already mapped to [alt]+[right].  So you do nothing at all, you should be able to use [alt]+[right] to move (forward) between words